# How to utilize C# properties correctly in this specific ASP.NET MVC scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have properties defined in my view model like so -

```
public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
            set {
                    FirstName = FullName.Split(null)[0];
                    LastName = FullName.Split(null)[1];
                }
        }


        public string FirstName { get; set; }


        public string LastName { get; set; }
```

My Razor View has this -

```
<label for="FullName">Name</label>
            @Html.TextBox("FullName", Model.FullName)
```

While I am able to set the full name and display it in the text box when the page loads, I am NOT able to retrieve the value  while form is submitted.

I need to retrieve the value from this text box too when the value is changed.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Either make FullName the property and First and Last methods that parse FullName or make FullName a method, which you could not use in  your razor view that combines First and Last. Doing what you are doing in the Setter of FullName is bad.

Comment: Should `FullName` even have a `set;` property?

Comment: In your setter you try to set `FirstName` and `LastName` properties to the value of `FullName` which in turn calls the getter which return the values of `FirstName` and `LastName` which are `null` because they have not been set.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're wanting to do here..

If you want to be able to "set" the `FullName` property and just split the string into chunks and assign those values to `FirstName` and `LastName`, you'd do it like this (and not use the property's name in itself):

```
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
            set
            {
                this.FirstName = value.Split(null)[0];
                this.LastName = value.Split(null)[1];
            }
        }
```

The issue in your code is that you're trying to use the `FullName` setter as a constructor, when in reality the First and LastName properties should be set individually and the `FullName` should just have a `get;` property just like you have (in my opinion).

Comment: Below lines are using FullName before it is set. 'FirstName = FullName.Split(null)[0];'
'LastName = FullName.Split(null)[1];'

Comment: I'm not sure what that means